# Convert T-SQL to ANSI-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ansi-sql

I want to convert my stored procedures from T-SQL to ANSI-SQL. Is there any tool or a checklist to do it?

Comment: Even if there was such a tool there is no database that uses ANSI SQL for their stored procedures.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`SET FIPS_FLAGGER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189781.aspx) option to help find non standard constructs that you are using.

Example

```
SET FIPS_FLAGGER 'INTERMEDIATE';

SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM master..spt_values;

SET FIPS_FLAGGER OFF;
```

Output

```
FIPS Warning: Line 1 has the non-ANSI statement 'SET'.
FIPS Warning: Line 3 has the non-ANSI clause 'TOP'.
```

There are also some online validators [for various versions of the standard](http://developer.mimer.com/validator/index.htm).